# WordPress Custom Post Type Admin Nested Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a couple of custom post types in Wordpress that are loosely related - they aren't directly connected such as with a taxonomy, but from a UI perspective they should be on the admin side. Both custom post types are showing up in the admin area, however they are top-level items and I'd prefer to have them grouped under a master menu item like so:

- Products `(top level item)`

  - All Products `(first custom post type)`
  - Product Groups `(second custom post type)`

While the two aren't directly related, it makes logical sense to group them together to help keep the admin area de-cluttered.

I've tried a couple of different things, but am certain it's a basic setting I'm not understanding. The most recent is the `add_submenu_page` option, but that doesn't seem to be working as I intended. Here is an example of the code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_child_menus');

function create_child_menus()
{
    add_submenu_page('products', 'Product Groups', 'Product Groups',     'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=product_groups');
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get a top-level grouping of admin items that contain multiple, non-related custom post types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you have custom posts types for 'products' and 'product_groups'.

When you register your 'product_groups' post type, use the following args:

```
'show_ui'              => true,
'show_in_menu'         => 'edit.php?post_type=products',
```

And do away with `add_submenu_page()`